# SQL Query to Get count of entries of a certain status inside channel

Tags: ee2, query, count, query-module

Right now I have this inside of a channel entries tag.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT total_entries FROM exp_channels WHERE channel_name = '{url_title}'"} 
{total_entries} 
{/exp:query}
```

Which provides me with the correct count as expected. (E.g. 8)

But say only 5 of those 8 are of the status I want to count.  How can I have it only count those entries?  Let's say the status is "featured" or "open"?  I feel this is not the correct method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I finally got it working, though not with SQL which I imagine is more efficient.  Behold my mess.  Note this is only because I'm having to nest it, and also match to url_title because of how we use Structure Listings.  Appreciate the help.

```
{exp:vmg_nested:channel:entries channel="{url_title}" dynamic="off" status="available" prefix="childlisting"}
{if 1 == '{childlisting:count}'}{childlisting:absolute_results}{/if}
{/exp:vmg_nested:channel:entries}
```

Used plugin: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vmg-nested

Comment: Good find, glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1):

It might work out easier to turn this into a short plugin, but would a query like this work? You'd need to pass in the id of the channel you're looking for.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT count(*) AS totaled FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id='{channel_id}' AND status='open'"}
{totaled}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: Very close, but because I'm working within Structure, I have to use channel_name instead of channel_id.  (wonky I know)  Would probably work for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

`exp_channels` is a table that contains summary information about the channels defined within your EE MySQL database, and one of the fields it contains is `total_entries` - so all your sql query is doing is picking that value from the table.  You could get the same information with a bit less complication by using the statistics module within EE.  Something like:

```
{exp:stats channel = '{url_title}'}
{total_entries}
{/exp:stats}
```

To get information on the status of entries within the channel, you'd need to run a query on the channel data itself (which is stored in the table `exp_channel_titles`).  This would require a more complicated sql query, but you could also do it using a regular `exp:channel:entries` call such as:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{url_title}" status="{status}"}
{total_results}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah stats unfortunately is very limited in ability.  I have something like the channel entries option here working, but it repeats the total_results multiple times and in my case, if count == 1 doesn't apply to me because I'm having to nest tags, difficult to explain.  But it's why I basically have to go with a query.

Comment: Not sure the 'limited ability' of stats is an issue - as your original sql is not doing anything special, just pulling the value of a field which you could do some other way.  The issue with counting entries with specific characteristics (e.g. status) is that you actually have to count them somehow - which makes you end up with more complex structures.  A sql query is fine, but there might be other ways too.